# In Dreamweaver CS5 for OSX, how do I expand and collapse ALL folders listed in its file explorer?

Tags: macos, dreamweaver

OSX's finder will expand ALL folders if you hold the Alt key and press right-arrow and collapse all with Alt+Left-arrow.  I've got a large project folder and it is tiresome to manually expand a lot of folders and then have to manually collapse them again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  The Dreamweaver interface doesn't support those shortcuts.